# Typescript -- Unable to understand in typescript -> return this._subscribe({onNext: onNext});

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

Reading an article regarding observable, found the code at the end of the question.

I am unable to understand the following lines ->

```
return this._subscribe({
                onNext: onNext,
                onError: onError || (() => {}),
                onCompleted: onCompleted || (() => {})
            });
```

**1)** I have never seen this syntax before, what is this exactly?

Using a typeof it says its an **object**, but it looks like to myself as an object inside a function, which does not make sense.

**2)** Since I did not understand the code, playing around found out that if I return

```
return {
                onNext: onNext,
                onError: onError || (() => {}),
                onCompleted: onCompleted || (() => {})
            }
```

The code will not reach the Point Two (look for -> // PointTwo below, after "return new Observable((obs)")

I assume the answer of the second question will be related to the first.

```
export class Observable<T> {
    /** Internal implementation detail */
    private _subscribe: any;

    /**
      * @constructor
      * @param {Function} subscribe is the function that is called when the 
      * observable is subscribed to. This function is given a subscriber/observer
      * which provides the three methods on the Observer interface:
      * onNext, onError, and onCompleted
    */
    constructor(subscribe: any) {
        if (subscribe) {
            this._subscribe = subscribe;
        };

    }


    // public api for registering an observer
    subscribe(onNext: any, onError?: any, onCompleted?: any) {
        if (typeof onNext === 'function') {
            return this._subscribe({
                onNext: onNext,
                onError: onError || (() => {}),
                onCompleted: onCompleted || (() => {})
            });
        } else {
          throw new Error("Please provide a function")
        }
    }

    static of(...args): Observable {
        return new Observable((obs) => {

       //pointTwo

            args.forEach(val => {
              console.log("3") 
              obs.onNext(val)
              });
            obs.onCompleted();

            return {
                unsubscribe: () => {
                    // just make sure none of the original subscriber's methods are never called.
                    obs = {
                        onNext: () => {},
                        onError: () => {},
                        onCompleted: () => {}
                    };
                }
            };
        });
    }
 }


 Observable.of(42).subscribe((num) => {console.log("number is -> " + num)})
```

Comment: The Observable constructor takes a function that it calls when it feels like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't TS specific. All they are doing is defining an object literal directly in the function invocation instead of before invoking the function:

```js
const functionThatTakesAnObject = (obj) => {
    console.log(obj);
};

const object = { prop1: true, somethingElse: '1' };

// pass in an object bound to a variable
functionThatTakesAnObject(object);

// define an object literal directly in the invocation
functionThatTakesAnObject({ prop1: true, somethingElse: '1' });
```

Comment: I had the same thought at start, but since we are passing an object, why it does not work if I return just the object (Question two)

Comment: Because `this._subscribe` is a function being called with that object. By just returning that object, `this._subscribe` is never invoked so the subscription isn't created.